# Transforming $\tan3x=k\tan x$ into $(3k-1)(\tan x)^2=k-3$

Tags: trigonometry

Given that $\tan3x=k\tan x$, by first expanding $\tan(2x+x)$ show that $$(3k-1)(\tan x)^2=k-3$$
I have tried just about everything that I could think of, unable to do it. Expanded once, then expanded $\tan2x$ in the expression, got nowhere

Comment: If you've done work for a problem, you should include it in your question so that we can ascertain where you might be running into trouble. In particular, it'd be helpful to include a statement of the relevant angle addition identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\tan3x=\frac{\tan2x+\tan x}{1-\tan2x\tan x}=\frac{\frac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2x}+\tan x}{1-\frac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2x}\tan x}=\frac{\tan x(3-\tan^2x)}{1-3\tan^2x}=k\tan x.$$
$$\frac{3-\tan^2x}{1-3\tan^2x}=k\implies \tan^2x=\frac{k-3}{3k-1}.$$

Answer (score 2):

**A Start:** As you know, you will need to use $\tan 2x=\frac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2 x}$ and $\tan(x+2x)=\frac{tan x+\tan 2x}{1-\tan x\tan 2x}$

If you do the expansion carefully, you will find that
$$\tan 3x=\frac{3\tan x-\tan^3 x}{1-3\tan^2 x}.$$

Set this equal to $k\tan x$, and simplify a bit.

You will be able to "cancel" a $\tan x$, **if** $\tan x\ne 0$. (That condition was unfortunately left out in the statement of the problem.)

Then manipulation should get you to where you want to go.

Comment: I did the exact same thing many times over! Just spotted a careless mistake in the algebra. Thanks man

Comment: You are welcome. These algebra slips can be a nuisance, hard to spot once one has made them.